# How to pass parent's latest state to child components that are elements of the state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Here, I meant parent and child to be `App()` and `Child()` respectively in the code below.

`App()` has a state, `myState`, which is an array of `Child()`.
Each `Child()` is basically a `<button>` with a certain property which holds `myState`,
and prints `id` of each `Child()` in `myState` to console when pressed.

What I expect is that when `Child()` is pressed, the latest `myState` is printed.
However, the `myState` acctually printed looks like the version of when it was passed, and not the latest.

Is there any solution to make the `myState` property passed to `Child()` point the latest `myState`?

Having added several children, you can check the `myState` of each `Child()` at the console by pressing them.
For example, pressing `ADD` button twice makes 2 additional buttons appear.
When the `Child()` initially added (`id` of `'initial'`) is pressed, it properly prints the `id`s, 1 and 2.
However, when `ID: 1` is pressed, nothing prints, and when `ID: 2`, only 1.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState([] as JSX.Element[]);

  /* 
    Below is a BAD state-passing example.
    setMyState makes myState point to an new array with another Child appended,
    although myState passed to the new Child references to the old array.
    Is there any way to pass the latest myState to Child???
  */
  function add() {
    setMyState([...myState, <Child key={myState.length + 1} id={myState.length + 1} myState={myState} />]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={add}>ADD</button>
      <Child key="initial" id="initial" myState={myState} />
      {myState}
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ id, myState }: any): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div>
      <button id={id} onClick={() => {
        for (let child of myState as JSX.Element[]) {
          console.log(child.props.id);
        }
        }}>ID: {id}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: when you call add function you set the state passing inside the value of state in that moment and not with the version after the set operation.  It is a strange use of state and the components: if you describe what you need to do I could help you to find a solution

Comment: @Max I appreciate your advise. What I actually want to do is, when a button of  a `Child()` is pressed, a new `Child()` gets added below the one pressed. However, I didn't include this adding-below functionality in the code above. I hope this will make sense to you.

Comment: I said it's strange because if you add a child after one child press, maybe, is more simple set a state with the number of press and render N child without insert them into a state. I hope I have explained